# Will a 10 speed chain perform adequately on a Shimano CUES 1x chairing?

Tags: compatibility, chainring, cues, 1-by-x

Situation:
10 speed Shimano hybrid/mountain straight bar shifter, 10 speed Shimano mountain/hybrid derailleur and 10 speed Shimano chain.

The person is looking for a 1x crank.

Shimano CUES crank seem like a good option. The 1x CUES chainring is narrow wide and meant to be used with any Shimano 11 speeds chain or the LG500.

Logic says that a 10 speed chain is compatible, but the chainring is 11 speed, so most probably narrower that a 10 speed chainring would be.

Will chain retention be fine and what other issues could arise? Intended use is commuting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No problem, the relevant metric for single chainrings is the inner chain width, that is the same for chains from 9 to 12 speed. So, using a 10-speed chain on an 11-speed chainring shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The question is not about the differences between LinkGlide and other transmissions, if the logic of 9-10-11 speed chains prevail or not, or the design of CUES.

Comment: @SuperBab My mistake, answer edited.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the input!